# How can you modify URL predictions on chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete

If you're on chrome, you can view your autocomplete predictions in `chrome://predictors/`.

However, there doesn't seem to be a way to modify them.

**How can you add, edit, or remove your predictors on chrome?**

Comment: the suggestions are trash, before they showed DOMAINS that started with that text, next they suggested URLS that contained the text now they show Google search predictions that contain the text. useless

Comment: Since a few week, for me the behavior has changed on my (linuxes) laptop and desktop: now it is stupidly the last fitting word in history, and no longer the fitting frequently used  ones (still shown correctly in chrome://predictors/ ).
Same for you ? Policy change ? new option ? (sync autocomplete flag does not change this). Or corruption of some DB ? (having to manually editing history each time is just ultra annoying).

Comment: I'm having the same issue and it really is annoying. I've tried setting various options but without any luck :-(

Comment: Have just found it. Go to  chrome://flags/#omnibox-drive-suggestions
and set that "Omnibox Google Drive Document suggestions" flag to Disabled.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `chrome://predictors/` list only keeps track of past guesses of Chrome.
When you start typing in stuff in the navigation bar, Google makes a guess at what you want a based on your browsing history. This predictors list keeps track of what
you typed, what Google guessed, and how accurate the guess was based on whether or not you clicked on it.

The list of past predictions is stored in the file described by the other
answer of user Hargrove, but it only for predictions done *in the past*.
Future predictions that are not covered by this predictors data, will be based
on your browsing history.

The history is stored for Windows in the folder
`C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`,
and for the Mac in
`/Users/{username}/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default`.
It is found inside an SQLite database file named `History` (no file extension),
specifically in an SQL table named `keyword_search_terms`.
For URL predictions, the table is called `urls`.

Deleting an entry in the drop-down list that is suggested by Chrome,
can be done from the Chrome user interface:
Highlight the entry and type:

- PC : <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>
- Mac : <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>

For doing other modifications, you will need
an SQLite database utility such as:
[DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/),
[MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/),
[DbVisualizer](https://www.dbvis.com/)
or
[SQLite Browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/) for OS X.

The interesting SQL table in the History database are
the `keyword_search_terms` table where items are found in the `lower_term` column.
URL predictions are found in the `urls` table.

Comment: `Shift + Delete` How did you figure that one out? One of those easter eggs of chrome. Thanks for sharing. Can confirm it works.

Answer (score 5):

An Easy way of accessing this data is by using a DB Browser, the easiest and one that I have used is called [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/).

Once downloaded go to

> C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Network Action Predictor

on your file explorer and then open with DB Browser and click the Browse Data tab. You should be able to edit these entries.