# Custom autocomplete in Chrome address bar

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete

I often use JIRA, and generally need to navigate to issues knowing their ID.

The address looks like `https://jira.mycompany.org/browse/myProject-ID`

Currently I just type JIRA, look for a suggestion being similar to my need (only the ID is different) and modify the ID.

Still I think typing e.g. `JIRA <ID>` and chrome would autocomplete it would be quicker.

I've tried to look for the solution and found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1399929/how-can-you-modify-url-predictions-on-chrome), however I don't think that solution is capable of doing such flexible modification as I need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way to do that in Chrome is to add a custom search engine:

Right-click the omnibox (address bar), click "Edit search engines".
This will open the "Manage search engines" page.
Click the Add button and enter:

```
Search engine : jira
Keyword : jira
URL : https://jira.mycompany.org/browse/%s
```

Finally click Save to create:

---

[image]

---

To query, type in the omnibox :

```
jira 1
```

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Firefox also has a similar mechanism called
[Custom Keywords](https://www-archive.mozilla.org/docs/end-user/keywords.html).

Comment: absolute legend