# How can I restore a Google Chrome URL-bar suggestion I accidentally removed?

Tags: google-chrome, history

Sometimes after typing a web address in Chrome and pressing tab a few times, I end up on the "Remove Suggestion" button and accidentally remove the suggestion I was trying to select. How can I restore a suggestion when this happens?

[image]

I tried "Reset settings to their original defaults," but that didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

I added the site I removed as a Bookmark, and then removed it, and this restored the site as the first suggestion when I type the page name into my URL bar once more.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome keeps predictions and history in databases, as described in
[this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1402013/8672).

Once deleted from its database, a prediction or a history item cannot
be restored.

Comment: "Once deleted from its database, a prediction or a history item cannot be restored." This suggests that a record of deleted items is being stored somewhere—otherwise, how could Chrome know not to suggest them again in the future? And if that's the case, what do I need to delete to reset autosuggestions behavior to a state in which I can re-add deleted items? Do I need to delete the database you mentioned, or something in my online Google account, or my entire Google account? (I realize the last of those options isn't practicable.)

Comment: Unfortunately, Google lumped history and predictions in the same SQLite database, although in different tables. More information in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/330125/8672). I don't know if deleting all the predictions will cause Chrome to start from zero. It was possible in the past to turn predictions off and on ([link](https://www.webnots.com/4-ways-to-disable-chrome-autofill-and-predictions/)), but this seems to have disappeared in the latest versions.

Comment: I tried moving the `urls` table in the `History` file (not sure if that's what you meant by "predictions"; `alter table urls rename to urls_bak;` is the command I ran, and `alter table urls_bak rename to urls` to reverse it), but that didn't have the desired effect. (It just deleted my history.)

I realized that the only functionality I cared much about was being able to search a website without visiting it, and I was able to do that by [adding a custom search engine](https://zapier.com/blog/add-search-engine-to-chrome/).

Comment: In fact, a hacky workaround for any use case is available through custom search engines: just make the keyword the URL that you want to appear as a suggestion, and make the URL the very same URL (without a `%s`).

Answer (score 0):

In the Chrome address bar, enter `chrome://settings/searchEngines`. Find the section called **Inactive Shortcuts**.

[image]

To restore a shortcut, click the corresponding **Activate** button.

Comment: What does search engines have to do with the restoration of the predictive URL autocomplete?

Comment: I guess I didn't say it in my original question, but my problem was specific to the search-engines feature. For example, in the screenshot in my original question, I'd accidentally removed the "Search Merriam-Webster" functionality. Following the steps in my answer restores it.